# show ggplot objects in rmarkdown as html svg code

Tags: r, svg, ggplot2

I would like to show `ggplot` objects on the browser as a svg using `rmarkdown`.

````
---
title: ""
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library(svglite)
library(ggplot2)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
      dev = "svglite",
      fig.ext = ".svg"
)
```

```{r, warning = F}
data(cars)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, qsec, color = factor(cyl))) +
      geom_point()

```
````

Everything works fine, but when I open it in Chrome and try to Inspect Element it turns out that the whole plot is within `<img>` tags. What I want to achieve is to create `rmarkdown` doc with html code with the whole `ggplot`.

I try to use `htmlSVG` function but it does not work on `ggplot`. I get an error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : argumemt is not a character vector
```

However, it works very well on basic plot - `htmlSVG(plot(data = sampled_df, z ~ price))` when I include it on `rmarkdown`.

Do you know it is possible to do the same thing with `ggplot` objects?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. All I had to do is to use `svgstring` from [`svglite`](https://svglite.r-lib.org/) which generate the whole code and then use `htmltools::HTML`.

````
---
title: ""
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library(svglite)
library(ggplot2)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
      dev = "svglite",
      fig.ext = ".svg"
)
```

```{r, warning = F, echo = F}
data(cars)

s <- svgstring()
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, qsec, color = factor(cyl))) +
      geom_point()

htmltools::HTML(s())

invisible(
      dev.off()
)

```
````

I use `invisible` function in order to hide a message generating by `dev.off()`.